# Equivalent to Perl Modulino for Ruby, Python?

Tags: python, ruby, perl, modulino

I know Perl has a design pattern known as a modulino, in which a library module file can act as both a library and a script.  Is there any equivalent to this in Ruby / Python?

I think this design pattern would be very useful for me; I'm writing workers that are fairly short, but also require a script to run them.  I think it would be convenient to have this all run from the same place.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python has `__name__`:

```
class MyClass(object):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("This will only run if you run the script explicitly, not import it")
```

If you run `python myscript.py`, the `print` function will run. If you import `MyClass` from `myscript`, the `print` will not.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for.  Now to find the equivalent for Ruby...

Answer (score 7):

This is the Ruby version:

```
if __FILE__ == $PROGRAM_NAME #equivalent: if __FILE__ == $0
  puts "This is the main file running, it is not being required."
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Perl 6 has this feature built in. You define a subroutine named `MAIN` that executes if you use the file as a script:

```
 sub MAIN { ... }
```

The signature for `MAIN` tells Perl 6 how to parse the command-line parameters. You can have multi-subs and Perl 6 will use the one whose signature matches. Here's the example from [Synopsis 6](https://design.perl6.org/S06.html#Declaring_a_MAIN_subroutine):

```
multi MAIN (Int $i) {...}   # foo 1
multi MAIN (Rat $i) {...}   # foo 1/2
multi MAIN (Num $i) {...}   # foo 1e6
multi MAIN ($i) {...}       # foo bar
```