# Do the `if __name__ == "__main__": ` like idioms have a name of design pattern?

Tags: python, ruby, perl, design-patterns, idioms

Do these following idioms (to write a module which is also an executable/runnable) have a name of design pattern?

In Python, we can write a module as an executable too with [if **name** == '**main**': idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do):

```python
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Similar idiom can be found in [Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687680/what-does-if-file-0-mean-in-ruby):

```ruby
if __FILE__ == $0
  main()
end
```

Also same effect can be achieved differently in [Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131304/in-perl-how-can-i-find-out-if-my-file-is-being-used-as-a-module-or-run-as-a-scr/1131490#1131490) too:

```perl
main() unless caller;
```

In Tcl, you may write:

```tcl
if {![info level] && [info script] eq $::argv0} {
    main
}
```

Although these are implemented in different ways, they share the same goal: make single script file both a module and an executable/runnable.
It seems to me a design pattern. How do you call them? I personally have been called them as *Executable Module* or *Runnable Module*, but I want to know the more common name if it exists.

Comment: As a side note, none of these languages' communities really goes in for the "design patterns" idea. Really, design patterns are repeatable workarounds for features that are missing in a language, and it's usually better to just have those features in the language. But that doesn't mean there aren't names for the languages' idioms, of course.

Comment: At least in Python and Tcl, I've seen the term "main guard" (or something "`__main__` guard" in Python, for obvious reasons) used for the more general, lower-level feature of guarding code from being run on import, at least in Python and Tcl. But that term applies whether you're using the idiom to write a source file that works both as a runnable script and as an importable module, or to guard against `multiprocessing` code running in child processes, or anything else. And I don't know of a cross-language name for the general idea of source-that-works-as-script-or-module (however implemented).

Comment: As for your own terms, the problem with "executable module" and "runnable module" is that, at least in Python, they both seem to imply a module that's runnable via `-m` more than one that's a script-or-module. (Plus, I've seen "runnable module" used to describe a module that has "entry point" functions that get auto-generated scripts at `pip install` time, which is yet another different thing.)

Answer (score 17):

In Perl, this pattern is known as a [*modulino*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16288846/equivalent-to-perl-modulino-for-ruby-python). I believe the term was coined by [brian d foy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2766176/brian-d-foy) in his book [*Mastering Perl*](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596527242.do). I don't often see the name applied for languages other than Perl, [but it does happen](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Modulinos).

Edit to add: the name goes back earlier than that. Here's an [article from 2004](http://www.drdobbs.com/scripts-as-modules/184416165) that uses the term.

Comment: And before that name was suggested, they were called progmods (coined by tchrist?)

Comment: Thank you for mentioning about the great articles for modulino. But I guess we can back further ago about this technique. Because I found [this post by Tim Bunce on c.l.p.m](https://gist.github.com/hkoba/37ec19af3c7a362f1288367c8f2adf91) from my local mail archives. So, It was publically known at least from 1995. (And I personally used similar technique in some of my perl codes written at 1999-2000).